# How can i extract a json object to googlesheets?

Tags: json, google-sheets, importdata

I would like to extract an object result of a json url to google sheets. Pls find the code that i use to import json data to google sheet: https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON

However, it extracts the data as a table. Is there a way to extract just one object result to a cell?

Here is the json url result. I need to get codeId value to a cell with importjson formula.

{"status":0,"statusAciklama":"success","codeId":"47348","groupId":"48962"}

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: this is the result of the json url:  {"status":0,"statusAciklama":"success","codeId":"47348","groupId":"48962"}.   I need to get only codeId value to google sheet with a formula.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTJSON(...); "codeId.:.(\d+)")
```

where `...` is your formula

Comment: Thank you, i used importdata formula at first with a delimiter, then used regeextract(cell;"codeId.:.(\d+)")to that result and that worked very well.